# Google Calendar API event insert always return 404 “not found” error iOS

Tags: ios, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I'm tried the calendar insert example from here : https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update

No matter which property i use, i always get the 404 "not found" error. Anyone can shed some light on this? Many thanks!!!

```
PUT https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/q4amm7fsk9rq97r3dmhisjie84&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json

Request Body : 



{
    attendees =     (
                {
            email = "xxxxxx.xxxx@gmail.com";
        }
    );
    end =     {
        dateTime = "2015-05-20T16:50:00+05:30";
    };
    start =     {
        dateTime = "2015-05-20T15:50:00+05:30";
    };
}
```

Responce:

```
 {    
   "error": {
    "errors": [
   {
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"message": "Login Required",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization"
    }
     ],
      "code": 401,
      "message": "Login Required"
         }
      }
```

Comment: What http status do you get?

Comment: @gnasher729 what you mean ???

Comment: You need to authenticate. Please follow the quickstarts guide in your language here: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try  **PUT** instead of Post
https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events/q4amm7fsk9rq97r3dmhisjie84&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json

```
{    
   "error": {
    "errors": [
   {
"domain": "global",
"reason": "required",
"message": "Login Required",
"locationType": "header",
"location": "Authorization"
    }
     ],
      "code": 401,
      "message": "Login Required"
         }
      }
```